# В справке по комментариям отсутствует локализация

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Отсутствует локализация у превью справки по комментариям.

> [image: скриншот]

Comment: Вот сейчас первый раз нажал эту ссылку :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевёл так:

> Комментарии используются для уточнения или указания на проблемы в сообщении. Устаревшие комментарии могут быть удалены.

> Узнать больше о комментариях

> Узнать больше о форматировании

Будет доступно после подгрузки transifex и сборки сайта.